# Extracting numbers from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numbers

I have a data frame df with one of the columns Entity as below

```
Entity
0: Received ' "bsm": ["entityID":"196609"
"entityID":"-1140719616"
"entityID":"196609"
"entityID":"196609"
"entityID":"196609"
"entityID":"10000227"
1: Received ' "bsm": ["entityID":"196609"
"entityID":"-1140719616"
```

I want to extract only numbers from the columns Entity and that too between the " " which are at the last can someone help me out.

can someone tell me a way to just extract numbers from the columns? I have also tried indexing but it is not possible.

Comment: Do you have access to the code that built this DataFrame? Rather than try to parse this malformed data, it might make more sense to fix the DataFrame creation step.

Comment: No, I don't have access to that code I just got the file in which the data frame looks like this. I have tried using str function also and also indexing as well but it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
df["Entity"].str.extract('"([-0-9"]*)"').str.strip()
```

**Output:**

```
0         196609
1    -1140719616
2         196609
3         196609
4         196609
5       10000227
6         196609
7    -1140719616
Name: Entity, dtype: object
```